# UISearchController on Form Sheet presentation

Tags: ios11, uisearchcontroller

I am currently migrating all my View Controllers inside my iPad application to use the iOS 11 standard searchController (on navigation item). Problem is when it is displayed on an iPad as a Form Sheet, the search bar is stuck on the top.

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

[image]

Any way I could fix this without disabling the "***hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation***' property?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using:

```
searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 8.0)

let b: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self])
b.setTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 8.0), for: .default)
```

And to take this effect only on iPad, I have put this code inside condition:

```
if (UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad)
```

However, I am not sure, if this is a correct way how to handle this.